# Showing images by using URL or download to the device?

Tags: android, firebase, picasso, firebaseui

I using Firebase UI with cards of RecyclerView and each card has text and a small image (90dp/90dp). I don't download the images to the device, I get the URI of the image and by using the `getDownloadUrl()` method, I get the image URL and show it with Picasso.

The problem is that if there are many records in the recyclerView, it takes some time to refresh the images if I scroll to the bottom or top of the page.

For example, if I scroll quickly to the bottom it shows the images seen in the top of the page for a second before showing the real images that need to be there.

I want to know if downloading the images to the device is the popular way today to load images quickly? Because I know that some apps do so.

Thank you.

Comment: use glide and cache the images

Comment: Your question is *primarily opinion-based*. With that said, why not just make use of a default image to be displayed while waiting for the corresponding images to load?

Comment: Do you know the answer Mr. AL?

Answer (score 2):

> For example, if I scroll quickly to the bottom it shows the images seen in the top of the page for a second before showing the real images that need to be there.

The reason why you see older images for newer places is because the RecylerView recycles its views. So by the time `getDownloadUrl()` in the following code,

```
getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
           if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               Picasso.with(context).
               load(task.getResult())
               into(holder.imageView);

           }
       });
```

is resolved the intended view can possibly be recycled to display content on a another position (in your case when you scroll down, a newer item at the bottom of the list).

*In general be wary of using callbacks to load any kind of data inside `onBindViewHolder` method of recycler view adapters.*

> I want to know if downloading the images to the device is the popular way today to load images quickly? Because I know that some apps do so.

Downloading image content locally and then displaying would indeed provide the best user experience, specially if the content you are loading doesn't change a lot. It will also reduce your firebase billing costs because you are billed per GB's downloaded. But you don't have to implement it manually.

**Solution**

First use a custom firebase request handler to handle firebase storage urls like `gs://somefirebasepath/somefile`. on the `load` method implement your caching logic.

```
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Request;
import com.squareup.picasso.RequestHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import static com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.LoadedFrom.NETWORK;

public class FirebasePicassoRequestHandler extends RequestHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean canHandleRequest(Request data) {
        return data.uri != null && "gs".equals(data.uri.getScheme();
    }

    @Override
    public Result load(Request request, int networkPolicy) throws IOException {
        //Implement your caching logic here, or load from network as follows
        StorageReference gsReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(request.uri.toString());

        StreamDownloadTask mStreamTask;

        InputStream inputStream ;

        mStreamTask = gsReference.getStream();

        try {
            inputStream = Tasks.await(mStreamTask).getStream();
            Log.i("FireBaseRequestHandler", "Loaded " + gsReference.getPath() );
            return new Result(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream), NETWORK);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new IOException();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
    }
}
```

And use `Picasso.Builder` to build a Picasso instance. And add your custom handler to Picasso. Optionally you can add an error listener to help debug issues with the handler if they occur.

```
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);

    builder.addRequestHandler(new FirebasePicassoRequestHandler());
    builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
            Log.e("Picasso", "Failure for " + uri.toString(), exception);
        }
    });

    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(builder.build());
```

Now we no longer need to resolve firebase storage urls in your adapter. Before doing the load request, we will cancel any pending requests to that `ImageView` and then load the firebase uri as follows,

```
    //inside your onBindViewHolder method

    Picasso.with(context).cancelRequest(imageViewInstance);
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load("gs://somefirebase/imagefile")
            .into(imageViewInstance);
```

and Picasso will handle the rest.